# Where do I ask where to ask?

Tags: support, site-recommendation, meta, asking-questions, faq-proposed

If I have a specific question I want to ask about, but I don't know which Stack Exchange site would be on topic for asking that question, where can I ask where to ask that question?

Is there any generic place where we can ask for advice? Is it here?

This is not about a specific question but in general.

**For example:** "Where should I ask for advice about fishing?", or if I need to know where I should ask "What would be the best fishing rod to fish for salmon?" (regardless of how good/bad these examples are)

Comment: on meta-meta se

Comment: I suggest a 'tollearn.meta"

Comment: I really enjoy just the fact that this question exists. It makes me calm. Computer scientists love meta, and sometimes play with meta meta. But none of these cases was so beautiful like this. Easy to read, and to understand. For everybody!

Comment: This has been answered as an aggregate question here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/390906/where-do-i-go-to-figure-out-in-which-stack-exchange-site-i-can-post-my-question

If you know how to make this a new answer which will be better than any of the answers to the individual two questions, please do so. I don't have time to figure it out. My new answer was automatically converted to a comment. 

Thank you.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

It's here and you've used the correct tag for it, [site-recommendation](/questions/tagged/site-recommendation).

As per the tag wiki excerpt:

> After looking through the site list, https://stackexchange.com/sites, don't know where to ask your question on the Stack Exchange Network? Give as much detail as possible about the question you'd like to ask, and the community will help you find the appropriate site.

A couple of tips:

- To increase the chances that the community can recommend you the correct site, consider including a copy of your intended question *in quote markup*.
- Be sure to explicitly phrase your question as a site recommendation (e.g. "where can I ask this question?"); if you don't do so, we may believe you're trying to get your *answer* here and your question may be marked as off-topic.

Comment: Ok, then I found nowhere it was written it was here. Maybe, we can do something about that (write it somewhere or, as I said, purpose another SE dedicated to that on area 51 maybe)

Comment: Well, your question has achieved just that. Asked and answered. This is the place. Any future such questions can be closed as a duplicate of this one. ;)

Comment: I think the OP was suggesting that an addendum go in the Help Centre or somewhere obvious, specifying that people can use this site as a "Where do I ask?" forum, so people don't have to search/ask the "Where do I ask where do I ask?" question. Or maybe I misunderstood.

Comment: Wow, the [tag:site-recommendation] tag really does belong on *this* question itself. How meta-meta.