# Where to ask Nitrokey boot question?

Tags: discussion, questions, site-recommendation

I'm not sure where to ask the question below. The following sites came in my mind:

1. unix.se: Because of my own affiliation with the Linux boot process, which the question is about for me.
2. security.se: It is very security related, the guys over there have a good overview of how such a system can not be as secure as I imagine
3. superuser.se: The linked resource mentions secured boot for Linux and Windows. So, the question and answer may help a larger userbase.

---

### Edit; not a duplicate

The suggested duplicate is not applicable.

1. It does not cover unix.se and superuser.se
2. I found only a statement regarding security, which doesn't rule out other options:

   > Everything that has to do with Information Security excluding the deeper aspects of cryptography and setting up your home antivirus.

Furthermore, I asked this question specifically about this question, based on instruction here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/168104/280891

> Don't know where to ask your question on the Stack Exchange Network? Let's find out where it could land. Do give an example.

---

## Q: Secure boot from Nitrokey storage?

Secure boot from Nitrokey storage?

I was looking into buying a NitroKey. To my surprise I found the following statement in the brochure:

> ### Keep a Secure Operating System With you at all  Times
>
> Securely boot Windows or Linux directly from Nitro
>   - key Storage. Nitrokey Storage encrypts and protects the system against manipulation, such as the installation of surveillance software via „Evil Maid“.

I am familiar with keeping a bootloader, kernel, and initramfs with encryption keys on a USB stick to prevent tampering. But in this case, I'm a bit confused about how it works? Most sources I found regarding its encryption mechanism, is that an application should ask you the device PIN to enter its storage. So unless it ships with some internal boot-loader logic, how to bring up a system in a state to can ask the PIN?

I've tried looking for secondary sources to this claim, but no avail:

*List with own research omitted for meta.se post*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-sites-do-i-post-on)

Comment: Your best bet is to take a quick peek at each of those sites and find out where 1) The tag selection is closest to your specific requirements and 2) The question style is similar. But from what I've seen, superuser looks like it has the most similar stuff.

Comment: I would ask on Security.se and when you get a tumbleweed, flag for a moderator to migrate to Linux.se... (opinion, so not an answer and just a comment)

Answer (score 2):

For now, I've tried my luck on superuser.com. As per @Chair's suggestion on tag selection. The [boot](/questions/tagged/boot) tag on Super User is quite common, around 9.2k questions. On security.se [boot](/questions/tagged/boot) tag is used only 69 times.