# Where to ask: How to keep integrity of profiles in dual boot Windows / Linux when updating Firefox and Thunderbird?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

This answer brought me here:

- https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/168104/149998

I found:

- [What is the right way to share a Thunderbird profile between Ubuntu and Windows, and between several users?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/370581/what-is-the-right-way-to-share-a-thunderbird-profile-between-ubuntu-and-windows)
- [Windows and Linux using same Firefox profile](https://superuser.com/questions/1258469/windows-and-linux-using-same-firefox-profile/1432343#1432343)
- and some blog and forum posts.

This is my question:

---

I'm sharing my Thunderbird and Firefox profiles between Windows 10 (as portable app) and Ubuntu 16 (dual boot).

I install all recommended updates.

This worked for quite some time, until the version difference between the Ubuntu respository and the portableapps.com version led to bugs:

- Ubuntu Firefox can't find or open its password safe and can't store passwords.
- Same for Ubuntu Thunderbird.
- Windows Firefox always needs to reinstall some plugins.
- Windows Thunderbird forgets that the 'Calendar' tab was opened before.

My guess is that these bugs are a result of accessing the same profile with different versions of Thunderbird and Firefox.

Some boilerplate to avoid discussions:

- I know that Mozilla doesn't support sharing of profiles.
- I use POP3 for some email accounts. I know this is an outdated method.
- I don't use Firefox Sync. That's my personal choice.
- I could wait and periodically check the different repositories and update when both versions are in sync, or manually install specific versions, but I don't.
- I'm frequently (about once a day) switching between both operating systems.

One of the versions will periodically (at least for some time) have a lower version than the other OS's version.

I'm afraid that with each update I risk permanently damaging my profile (when accessing it with the older version).

How can I share profiles and keep their integrity?

---

Which Stack Exchange site(s) can this question be asked on?

Answer (score 1):

This question appears to be [on-topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) on [Super User](https://superuser.com).