# Where is the testing area for new users/members?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I read this:
*[Where do I ask where to ask?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168103/where-do-i-ask-where-to-ask)*

And I want to ask:

Where can new users/members test editor features, in a way which will automatically delete threads/questions after a few days, and not store them for posterity?

I am used to the existence of such places on other sites, but here I can not find one.

Can you point me to them, or if it does not exist, is it possible to create one on this platform?

Comment: In the [Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox).  But they will not be auto-deleted.

Comment: So this would be not the same. Imagine that all users will try to check whats new on new editor which is tested currently here:[Opt-in alpha test for a new Stacks editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360033/opt-in-alpha-test-for-a-new-stacks-editor/).

Comment: Ah.  If it's for the new editor, and you've found a bug or have a request, go ahead and post there!  But if it's just a test, then go to the Sandbox.

Comment: `If it's for the new editor, and you've found a bug or have a request, go ahead and post there!` Yes, I know. Currently I doing my test, and posting there. I was just used to the fact that I can test in a separate forum, something like creating a new type of "Stack communities" where all messages are thrown into the trash, for example after 24 hours.

Comment: @MichałLipok we don't have a feature that auto deletes answers the way you're describing and haven't ever, as far as I'm aware. We're 100% ok with you using the sandbox for this, as others have said.

Comment: But there are a number of strange things around the Sandbox, namely the dodgy "Not the answer you're looking for" text at the bottom, so don't be surprised ;)

Comment: I just [search in help center for sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/search?q=sandbox) and I found that there is only 2 times  mentioned about 'sandbox'. Maybe special article in help center would be "more accurate" ?

Comment: @Ollie it looks like this is realy strange and mysterious lair.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To *test* editor features, go to [the Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox).  If [you’ve found a bug or have a request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360071/where-is-testing-area-for-new-users-members?noredirect=1#comment1201548_360071), then go ahead and post it at the [Alpha test for the new Stacks editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360033/opt-in-alpha-test-for-a-new-stacks-editor/).  But, AFAIK, there is no Sandbox post that will auto-delete your posts after a certain amount of time.

Comment: The Formatting Sandbox post used to have its answers archived every now and then by Shog9 who'd do it by manually tinkering with the database; sadly as he's gone now, that's not happening anymore.

Comment: But I see that this is not The Formatting Sandbox affects users/members Reputationa and Badges. And just now I realize that this was one of the reason why asked about separate forum/group for this kind of purpuoses. I thought any activity in a place like this shouldn't affect the statistics.

Comment: As the sandbox is community wiki, it does not affect a users reputation @MichałLipok